# Генерация docx средствами php

Tags: php, xml, xmlparser, docx

Стоит следующая задача:
Существует шаблон док-та в формате docx, в котором есть маркеры (например,{{dl.name.no-mod.req}} ). Необходимо вместо маркеров подставить рассчитанные параметры.

После того, как я разархивирую docx, в исходном xml часть подобных маркеров разбивается различными тегами:

```
<w:p>
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="Normal"/>
            <w:rPr></w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
            <w:rPr></w:rPr>
            <w:t>«{{dl.name.</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>no</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
            <w:rPr></w:rPr>
            <w:t>-</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>mod</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
            <w:rPr></w:rPr>
            <w:t>.</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>req</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
            <w:rPr></w:rPr>
            <w:t xml:space="preserve">}}»</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
```

Соответственно, моё регулярное выражение их не находит.

Из-за чего происходит разбиение в исходном шаблоне?
Есть ли способ избежать подобного? Возможно, стоит, изменить формат маркеров? 
Или же нужно как-то по иначе работать с данными (сейчас, работаю с исходным xml, как с обычной строкой - ищу все вхождения подобных маркеров, рассчитываю их значения, после запаковываю обратно в docx архив)?

Comment: Взгляните на библиотеку PhpOffice https://github.com/phpoffice. С ее помощью свою задачу вы решите быстро и легко.

Comment: @dmitry, к сожалению, используя эту библеотеку столкнусь с этой же проблемой (вкратце, она описана тут: http://myopencart20.blogspot.ru/2016/11/zamena-texta-v-shablone-docx-php.html - в xmlке пишется куча информации, которая разбивает исходные маркеры)
Частично помогла замена точек на "-", но столкнулся с другим - если word считает маркер за неправильно написанное слово - он тоже об этом спешит сообщить в xml, разбив исходный маркер тегами.

Видимо, необходимо как-то иначе производить поиск.